# print first 10 list items, then every one thereafter ending in 5 or 0

Tags: python, python-3.x

results list: 80 rows(entries) containing 3 items each (year, age, amt).  I want to print first 10, thereafter print only a row whose age ends in 0 or 5.

```
for row in results:
  if row = results[:9] or results[10:].row[1] % 5 == 0:
```

There is a syntax problem with the second part.

Comment: You can't do assignment (`=`) in an `if` statement (unlike in C/C++). Did you mean to use `==`? I am not following what you're trying to accomplish here. Try giving an example input -> example output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use assignment in an expression (`row = results[:9]`). Assignment is a statement.

That's not how you test if you are in the first 10 rows however. Instead, add a counter to the rows with the [`enumerate()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), and test against that row counter:

```
for i, row in enumerate(results):
      if i < 10 or row[1] % 5 == 0:
```

Comment: yea, I mis-typed; should have been if row ==

Comment: @Dennis: that's your syntax error however. There are also *runtime* errors in your code, which I address in the rest of the answer.

Comment: Assuming I had the == in the line of code, how would I modify MY CODE to do what I want -- I only need to know how to code the part about accessing any row in the list (After the 10th row) where the age ends in 0 or 5 -- I know the .row[1] is not correct.  Is it possible to make my code correct?

Comment: @Dennis: That's what I did, I gave you the correct code. No, your approach can't work.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier to use a counting index in this situation

```
for i in range(len(results)):
    if (i <= 9 or row[i] % 5 == 0):
         print(row[i])
```